# New file not getting called on renameTo()

Tags: java, linux, file-rename

I used the following code to edit the file OIMV2Migration.sh on linux.

```
    String oldFileName = "OIMV2Migration.sh";//file to be edited
    String tmpFileName = "tmp_try.dat"; //new file containing changes
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
                  try {
                     br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFileName));
                     bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFileName));
                     String line;
                     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (line.contains("SURBHI")) {
                           line = line.replace("SURBHI MITTAL" , "SURBHI GUPTA");}
                        bw.write(line+"\n");
                     }
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                     return;
                  } finally {
                     try {
                        if(br != null)
                           br.close();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                        //
                     }
                     try {
                        if(bw != null)
                           bw.close();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                        //
                     }}

                 //delete the old file
                  File oldFile = new File(oldFileName);;
                  oldFile.delete();
                 //rename the new file to old file        
                  File newFile = new File(tmpFileName);
                  System.out.println(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
                  Boolean success = newFile.renameTo(oldFile);
                  System.out.println(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Here , the file is getting updated correctly , but the absolute path of the newFile is always pointing to "tmp_try.dat , both before renameTo() and after renameTo() is executed.

I got to know from stack overflow link that the absolute path of the file instance does not change , it remains same.
But my problem is there is another file in my system idmlcm.sh which is internally calling OIMV2Migration.sh.But after this method is executed , idmlcm.sh is not able to call OIMV2Migration.sh as if it cant find this file.
Although the file exists in the correct directory only.

Answer (score 0):

According to [JAVA Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File))

Behavior of *renameTo* :

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and **it
>   might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists**. The return value should always be checked to make sure
>   that the rename operation was successful.

In your case, first you are deleting `oldFile` and than rename that `tmpFile` to `oldFileName`, that actually works perfect, but when you call `newFile.getAbsolutePath()` will print path of `tmpFile` because the `Object newFile` still refers to old path only. You need to re-create the `File Object` to access your renamed `File`.

Comment: That I understood , but then why my script idmlcm.sh is unable to call OIMV2Migration.sh after this operation is performed?

Comment: @SurbhiMittal create new object like this - `newFile = new File(oldFile.getAbsolutePath());` this will create new file object of renamed file.